# Rspec - Should we use fixtures to test a database query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Using `ruby(1.8.7)`, `rails(2.3.8)`, `rspec(1.3.1)` and `rspec-rails(1.3.3)` how do I test a method that is full of complex SQL queries? Is there a way to make use of stubs and mocks. For example, a method like:

```
class Bucket << ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :students
  def populate_students_subassesmentwise(subassesment, mentor)
    student_ids = Mark.find(:all,
      :joins => "#{self.student_current_klass} #{self.current_mentors}",
      :conditions => ["marks.subject_id = ? AND st.klass_id = ? AND 
                   IF(sub.is_elective IS TRUE, 
                     (se.student_id = st.id AND se.subject_klass_id = marks.klass_id AND se.student_klass_id = st.klass_id AND marks.subject_id = se.subject_id),
                     (marks.klass_id = st.klass_id))
                   AND u.account_enabled IS TRUE AND sub.active IS TRUE AND k.active IS TRUE AND marks.markable_id = ? AND marks.markable_type = ?
                   AND ROUND(marks_obtained/marks_total*100) BETWEEN ? AND ? ",
                   mentor.subject_id, mentor.klass_id, subassesment.id, "Subassesment", min_range, max_range],
      :group => "marks.id").collect(&:student_id)

    self.assign_students(student_ids) # This is a call to another instance method that runs a query to find the students having ids equal to student ids and assign it to the students attr_accessor
  end
end
```

As you can see there are a lot of JOIN, IF and WHERE clauses, that are more of talking in 'DBMS' terms, how do I write tests in Rspec that would mock this query? Or should we use fixtures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would test this using fixtures (or rather, FactoryGirl). Since you're really testing your sql/database code it seems silly to me not to test this in the database. Unless you have a seperate sql unittesting setup or something (which seems like overkill to me ;) (in most scenarios))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of spaghetti SQL like this, because it becomes painfully difficult to test. I would say the easiest way to test this would be to do something like the following:

1. Add "Buckets" to your test database
2. Make sure you put some of them in states that these conditions will/will not pass
3. Test results, making sure you did get what you wanted and didn't get what you didn't

That's how I would do it, anyway.

Hope this helps!